# MySQL suddenly not working on Windows Server 2003

Tags: mysql, windows

I installed PHP and MySQL on our windows 2003 server about 3 months ago.  Everything has been working wonderfully, but for some reason when I came into work this morning, the service had stopped working.  I proceeded to start the service up again, shortly there after the service stopped again.   In the Event Log for the server I have the following errors:

Application Event:   Source: Application Error, Category 100, Event ID: 1000, Description: Faulting application mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x002aafd7.

System Event: Source: Service Control Manager, Description: The MySQL service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).

I figured something was just buggy, so I rebooted the server, same problem.  As far as I know, nothing was changed on the server over the weekend.

When I launched MySQL Administrator that installed with it, And click on the Server logs, their is no information, and most boxes are grayed out.

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try examining the MySQL error log.

A possible location would be:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\data\server-name.err

Comment: Currently Running MySQL 5.1.   I searched through the 5.1 directory for *.err files, and none where located.  The only directories in the MySQL Server 5.1 folder are:  bin, Docs, and Share.   I looked through each directory and did not see anything that looked like an error file.

Comment: Where is your data folder?
I just check a 5.1 install on my development machine and it has a data folder.

Comment: The my.ini file will specify the location:

ie 

#Path to the database root
datadir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"

Comment: I believe the Data folder is located at:  D:\MySQL Datafiles

The only file in that directory is called ibdata1 (with no extension??) and the file is 18,432KB in size.

Comment: Alright, I found the data directoy, it was set up for:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\

In the Data folder, I found the .err file.   Going to try and attach it.

Comment: I have copied the error code to:

http://pastebin.com/m103c467a

Thanks for your help!